# I want to call new action after completing the conversation with user on secondary receiver protocol

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, rasa

I want to call new actions as I complete the conversation with the user on the secondary receiver protocol and I also want to pass the thread again to the primary receiver.

[image]

After the conversation ended, I want my chatbot to be started again.

Comment: Please provide some details about how you've coded this, what you've tried, and where it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart the conversation, include `Restarted()` in the events returned from your last custom action:

```
class ActionName(Action):
    def name(self):
...
        return "action_name"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
...
        return [Restarted()]
```

You can customise `action_session_start` to check some condition and pass it to the appropriate receiver as well